# Python Tic Tac Toe using Turtles. (User has to input numbers to corresponding squares.)

Tags: python, module, tic-tac-toe, turtle-graphics

Why isn't the refresh2 function doing anything?  It's supposed to check if the O player wins, but it is not doing so.  I really need help to get the second refresh function working properly.  Any help would greatly be appreciated.  Also, after a player wins, it is supposed to draw a line through where the player wins.  It does, but it is very inaccurate and skewed.  Please notify me at powdercheeze@gmail.com if you have any answers (BY FRIDAY)

```
from turtle import *
from os import *
import math
list1 = {1: (-100,100),2: (0,100), 3: (100,100), 4: (-100,0), 5: (0,0), 6: (100,0), 7: (-100,-100), 8: (0,-100), 9: (100,-100)}
list2 = [];list3 = [];list4 = {1: (-100,100),2: (0,100), 3: (100,100), 4: (-100,0), 5: (0,0), 6: (100,0), 7: (-100,-100), 8: (0,-100), 9: (100,-100)}
t = Turtle();
def turtle1():
    t.home();resetscreen()
    t.speed(10000);t.up();t.backward(150);t.pendown();t.forward(300);t.left(90);t.up();t.forward(1/3*300);t.pendown();t.left(90);t.forward(300);t.right(180)
    t.forward(100);t.left(90);t.forward(100);t.right(180);t.forward(300);t.right(180);
    t.forward(100)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(100)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(100)
    t.right(180)
    t.forward(300)
def input1():
    a = int(input("X player, enter a square: "))
    if a in list1:
        t = Turtle();t.up();t.setposition(list1[a]);t.left(90);t.forward(50);t.pendown();t.right(45);
        t.forward(40*math.sqrt(2));
        t.left(180);
        t.forward(80*math.sqrt(2))
        t.left(180)
        t.forward(40*math.sqrt(2))
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(40*math.sqrt(2))
        t.right(180)
        t.forward(80*math.sqrt(2))
        list1.pop(a)
        list2.append(a)
        refresh2() 
    if a not in list1:
        print("Enter a valid square, or one that hasn't been taken yet.")
        input1()
def input2():
    b = int(input("O player, enter a square: "))
    if b in list1:
        c = Turtle();c.up();c.setposition(list1[b]);
        c.down()
        c.circle(47)
        list1.pop(b)
        input1()
        list3.append(b)
        refresh();refresh2() 
    if b not in list1:
        print("Enter a valid square, or one that hasn't been taken yet.")
        input2()
def refresh():
    global list2;global list1;
    if 1 in list2 and 2 in list2 and 3 in list2 or 4 in list2 and 5 in list2 and 6 in list2 or 7 in list2 and 8 in list2 and 9 in list2: 
        print("The X Player Won! ");list2.sort();t.up();t.left(45);t.forward(80*math.sqrt(2));t.setposition(list4[int(list2[1])]);t.down();t.goto(list4[list2[int(len(list2)-1)]])
        z = input("Do you want to play again? ")
        if z == "y" or z == "Y": list2 = [];list1 = list4;turtle1();input1()
    if 1 in list2 and 4 in list2 and 7 in list2 or 2 in list2 and 5 in list2 and 8 in list2 or 3 in list2 and 6 in list2 and 9 in list2:
        print("The X Player Won! ");list2.sort();t.up();t.left(45);t.forward(80*math.sqrt(2));t.setposition(list4[int(list2[1])]);t.down();t.goto(list4[list2[int(len(list2)-1)]])
        z = input("Do you want to play again? ")
        if z == "y" or z == "Y": list2 = [];list1 = list4;turtle1();input1()
    if 1 in list2 and 5 in list2 and 9 in list2 or 3 in list2 and 5 in list2 and 7 in list2:
        print("The X Player Won! ");list2.sort();t.up();t.left(45);t.forward(80*math.sqrt(2));t.setposition(list4[int(list2[1])]);t.down();t.goto(list4[list2[int(len(list2)-1)]])
        z = input("Do you want to play again? ")
        if z == "y" or z == "Y": list2 = [];list1 = list4;turtle1();input1()
    if len(list1) == 0:print("Tie!")
    else:
        input2()
def refresh2():
    if 1 in list2 and 2 in list2 and 3 in list2 or 4 in list2 and 5 in list2 and 6 in list2 or 7 in list2 and 8 in list2 and 9 in list2: 
        print("The O Player Won! ");list2.sort();t.up();t.left(90);t.forward(50);t.setposition(list4[int(list2[1])]);t.down();t.goto(list4[list2[int(len(list2)-1)]])
        z = input("Do you want to play again? ")
        if z == "y" or z == "Y": list2 = [];list1 = list4;turtle1();input1()
    if 1 in list3 and 4 in list3 and 7 in list3 or 2 in list3 and 5 in list3 and 8 in list3 or 3 in list3 and 6 in list3 and 9 in list3:
        print("The O Player Won! ");list3.sort();t.up();t.left(90);t.forward(50);t.setposition(list4[int(list3[1])]);t.down();t.goto(list4[list3[int(len(list3)-1)]])
        z = input("Do you want to play again? ")
        if z == "y" or z == "Y": list3 = [];list1 = list4;turtle1();input1()
    if 1 in list3 and 5 in list3 and 9 in list3 or 3 in list3 and 5 in list3 and 7 in list3:
        print("The O Player Won! ");list3.sort();t.up();t.left(90);t.forward(50);t.setposition(list4[int(list3[1])]);t.down();t.goto(list4[list3[int(len(list3)-1)]])
        z = input("Do you want to play again? ")
        if z == "y" or z == "Y": list3 = [];list1 = list4;turtle1();input1()
    if len(list1) == 0:print("Tie!")
turtle1()
while True:
    input1()
    input2()
```

Comment: "Please notify me at powdercheeze@gmail.com if you have any answers (BY FRIDAY)" You are literally demanding an answer, atleast try to be more polite.

Can you explain what each list is supposed to do? What do you think the refresh function is doing? Does it give any errors? Also this is not how you design a tic tac toe game.

Comment: **Answers are provided here only**. That's what this site is for. To help everyone & not just one individual. Also,being a little polite always helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name:        TIC-TAC-TOE
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import turtle
turtle.speed(0)

def MakeCircle():
    turtle.pencolor("black")
    turtle.circle(12)
    turtle.pencolor("white")

def MakeCross():
    turtle.pencolor("black")
    turtle.lt(45)
    turtle.forward(19)
    turtle.rt(180)
    turtle.forward(9.5)
    turtle.rt(90)
    turtle.forward(9.5)
    turtle.rt(180)
    turtle.forward(19)
    turtle.pencolor("white")

def MakeTable():
    turtle.forward (90)
    turtle.rt(180)
    turtle.forward(60)
    turtle.lt(90)
    turtle.forward(60)
    turtle.lt(180)
    turtle.forward(90)
    turtle.lt(180)
    turtle.forward(60)
    turtle.lt(90)
    turtle.forward(60)
    turtle.lt(180)
    turtle.forward(90)
    turtle.lt(180)
    turtle.forward(60)
    turtle.lt(90)
    turtle.forward(60)
    turtle.lt(180)
    turtle.forward(90)
    turtle.pencolor("white")
    turtle.goto(45,-15)

def PlayFirstCircle():
    play=raw_input(" CIRCLE : Where do you want to play? : ")
    i=1
    if play == "A":
        play = (4,15)
    elif play == "B":
        play = (4,-15)
    elif play == "C":
        play = (4,-45)
    elif play == "D":
        play = (34,15)
    elif play == "E":
        play = (34,-15)
    elif play == "F":
        play = (34,-45)
    elif play == "G":
        play = (64,15)
    elif play == "H":
        play = (64,-15)
    elif play == "I":
        play = (64,-45)
    elif play == "END":
        print " GAME FINISHES : Cross Wins!"
        i=0
        turtle.bye()
    turtle.goto(play)
    MakeCircle()
    return i

def PlayCircle():
    play=raw_input(" CIRCLE : Where do you want to play? : ")
    i=1
    if play == "A":
        play = (14,3)
    elif play == "B":
        play = (14,-27)
    elif play == "C":
        play = (14,-57)
    elif play == "D":
        play = (44,3)
    elif play == "E":
        play = (44,-23)
    elif play == "F":
        play = (44,-57)
    elif play == "G":
        play = (74,3)
    elif play == "H":
        play = (74,-27)
    elif play == "I":
        play = (74,-57)
    elif play == "END":
        print " GAME FINISHES : Cross Wins!"
        i=0
        turtle.bye()
    turtle.goto(play)
    MakeCircle()
    return i

def PlayCross():
    play=raw_input(" CROSS : Where do you want to play? : ")
    i=1
    if play == "A":
        play = (10,10)
    elif play == "B":
        play = (10,-20)
    elif play == "C":
        play = (10,-50)
    elif play == "D":
        play = (40,10)
    elif play == "E":
        play = (40,-20)
    elif play == "F":
        play = (40,-50)
    elif play == "G":
        play = (70,10)
    elif play == "H":
        play = (70,-20)
    elif play == "I":
        play = (70,-50)
    elif play == "END":
        print " GAME FINISHES : Circle Wins!"
        i=0
        turtle.bye()
    turtle.goto(play)
    MakeCross()
    return i

print "\n TIC - TAC - TOE "
print "\n The objective of the game is to complete a line of 3 circles(O) "
print " or crosses (X), before your opponent. (2 Player Game) "
print " Circle plays first. If a player has won, enter 'END' in input. "
print
print " Play according to this : "
print " A D G "
print " B E H "
print " C F I "

MakeTable()
PlayFirstCircle()
turtle.seth(0)
PlayCross()
turtle.seth(0)
PlayCircle()
turtle.seth(0)
PlayCross()
turtle.seth(0)
PlayCircle()
turtle.seth(0)
PlayCross()
turtle.seth(0)
PlayCircle()
turtle.seth(0)
PlayCross()
turtle.seth(0)
PlayCircle()
turtle.seth(0)
```

Comment: im in grade 11, this is the best i can do :)